# How to change a Heroku nodejs worker to avoid memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, memory-leaks

Here's a node js worker on Heroku:

```
var Worker = require('./worker.js')
...
Worker.performJob(data) //data is a small object with just 3 attributes
```

worker.js:

```
var Worker = {}
Worker.performJob = function (data) {
  //read lots of data into memory, call other functions with this data as parameters
  var hugeData = readFromDb()
  Worker.processStuff(hugeData)
}

Worker.processStuff = function (hugeData) {
  ...
}

module.exports = Worker
```

The worker listens to some events and starts processing data, over and over again.
In time, the memory used by the worker grows -- it's not deallocated when performJob() finishes, even though all huge variables are local.
This article http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/05/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/ hints that it might be because of the Worker global variable, at it keeps references to functions.

How should the worker be written to avoid this?

UPDATE
I've changed the worker by moving functions in the same .js file. Now it reads

```
performJob(data)

function performJob(data) {
  //read lots of data into memory, call other functions with this data as parameters
  var hugeData = readFromDb()
  processStuff(hugeData)
}

function processStuff(hugeData) {
  ...
}
```

Still, the memory grows after each task performed, and remains to that level when idle (as shown by https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-runtime-metrics), then grows again after another task...

Comment: Growing memory is there because you're keeping references to objects.
Is readFromDB sync? Maybe the problem is there?
Also, how are you calling this worker? Are you just spawning a new worker on each new data push?

Comment: Thanks Zlatko. readFromDB is async, wrote it that way for readability.
I was expecting that hugeData array would be freed after processStuff() is done, but that seems to remain.

The worker starts once, and then listens to events and calls performJob()

Comment: Well, that dangling reference might be in the call to db?